# How to implement an initializer list for user defined type? (analogus to std::vector initializer list)

Tags: c++, c++11, initializer-list

`std::vector` can be initialized as

```
std::vector<std::string> words1 {"the", "frogurt", "is", "also", "cursed"};
```

[Reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector)

Now if want to achieve the similar functionality for one of my types, how do I go about doing it? How should I implement the constructor for this functionality?.

How does the standard support me achieving this (reference to standard will be most helpful)?. Basically, if you could teach me how it's implemented for `std::vector` it will be sufficient.

Can this also be done prior to C++11?

Also, can I have a POD struct type initializer list so that I can have values with different types to initialise my type?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Create a constructor which takes a `std::initializer_list` as a parameter:

```
#include <vector>
#include <initializer_list>

template <typename T>
struct foo
{
private:
    std::vector<T> vec;

public:

    foo(std::initializer_list<T> init) 
      : vec(init)
    { }
};


int main()
{
    foo<int> f {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
}
```

`std::vector` does this is almost exactly the same way (although utilizing `begin()` and `end()` - `std::initializer_list` has iterators much the same way as other containers do). From `gcc`:

```
  vector(initializer_list<value_type> __l,
     const allocator_type& __a = allocator_type())
  : _Base(__a)
  {
_M_range_initialize(__l.begin(), __l.end(),
            random_access_iterator_tag());
  }
```

Edit: I'm not 100% what you're trying to do, but you may simply be able to use *uniform initialization* to get what you want:

```
struct bar
{
private:

    int i;
    double j;
    std::string k;

public:

    bar(int i_, double j_, const std::string& k_)
      : i(i_), j(j_), k(k_)
    { }

};

int main()
{
    bar b {1, 2.0, "hi"};
}
```

Comment: the values in the initializer list has to be of the same type right? can i have different type(as if like initializing a POD struct)?

Comment: @Koushik They must be all of one type. It's effectively stored as an array of type `T`.

Comment: oh so icant have a POD struct like initializer list is it?

Comment: Note, the constructor is unnecessary for this uniform initialization example, because the type is an aggregate. (It works as long as there are no constructors.)

Comment: @Potatoswatter With `public` member variables, yeah.

Comment: @Yuushi thanks thats what i'm after:-) sorry it was confusing

Comment: What's the bonus comparing `bar b(1, 2.0, "hi");` ?

Comment: @UniversE sugarcoating:-) the same way why we dont really need operator overloading.

Comment: If you want your list-initialization to also work unsurprisingly with zero-size initializer-list, you also need to add a default constructor with the corresponding semantics. For more details see http://akrzemi1.wordpress.com/2013/05/14/empty-list-initialization/

Comment: @Andrzej i recently started following your blog starting with "sept 2011's destructors that throw" . its really helpful. thanks for such a good site.

Comment: @Andrzej Thanks for that, I was also unaware of empty initializer lists causing problems.

Comment: @UniversE Koushik is actually incorrect the bonus is uniform initialization prevents narrowing, look it up :)

Comment: @Koushik not sugar coating see above comment

Comment: @aaronman yeah i actually learnt about it after going to the link in above comment . Hope UniversE is not misguided by my comments.

Answer (score 2):

I guess if you want a *custom* initializer list, the following should suffice?

```cpp
template <typename T>
class Initializer
{
private:
    T* _List;
    size_t len;

public:
    Initializer()
        : _List(nullptr), len(0) {}

    template <typename... _Rest>
    Initializer(T _first, _Rest... _rest)
        : _List(new T[sizeof...(_rest) + 1]{_first, _rest...}), 
          len(sizeof...(_rest) + 1) {}

    Initializer<T>& operator=(Initializer<T> &&) = delete; // move operator [Implement your own if you want.]
    Initializer<T>& operator=(const Initializer<T>& ) = delete; // copy operator [Implement your own if you want.]

    const T operator[] (size_t index) const noexcept
        { return _List[index]; }
    T& operator[] (size_t index) noexcept
        { return _List[index]; }

    const T* begin() const noexcept
        { return _List; }
    T* begin() noexcept
        { return _List; }

    const T* end() const noexcept
        { return &_List[len]; }
    T* end() noexcept
        { return &_List[len]; }

    size_t length() const noexcept
        { return len; }

    ~Initializer() noexcept
        { _List != nullptr ? delete[] _List : void(0); }
};
```

---

**Examples:**
Passing it as a function constructor:

```cpp
void func(Initializer<int> list)
{
    // Nothing. Absolutely nothing...
}

int main()
{
    func({ 104, 101, 108, 108, 111}); // Don't translate to ASCII ;)
}
```

Initializing it *normally*:

```cpp
Initializer<const char*> AListOfStrings = {
   "This is a test",
   "Mic testing 123",
   "Oh good it works!"
};
```

---

Now I don't know if there are any edge cases to this way, but if there are you could perhaps let me know about it in the comments and i could try to fix it.

Anyway I think this should be ok.

Answer (score 0):

If someone is still seeking to get yet another answer for this question then you can  get the benefit from `typeid` like:

```
template <typename Type>
void check_type( Type par ){
   if( typeid(Type) == typeid(std::string()) ) {} //check for string type
   if( typeid(Type) == typeid(int) ){} //is int

}
```