# Initialize C++ array member in template class

Tags: c++, arrays, templates

I need to implement a safe array class that controls index when accessing underlying C array:

```
template <typename T, int N> class SafeArray
{
public:
    T &operator[](int index)
    {
        assert(0 <= index && index < N);
        return m_data[index];
    }
private:
    T m_data[N];
};
```

And instead of `bool a[3];`, now I write `SafeArray<bool, 3> a;`.

How do I support array initialization like `bool b[3] = {false};`? I mean what should I do to get `b.m_data[] = {false, false, false}` after `SafeArray<bool, 3> b;` has been constructed?

I guess I should add a constructor to `SafeArray`, but what would be a body of that constructor? Template parameter `T` can be anything, not necessarily `bool`. I am using pre-C++11.

Comment: std::initializer_list<T>.check out one of my [questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16455029/how-to-implement-an-initializer-list-for-user-defined-typeanalogus-to-stdvec)

Comment: do you want to re-implement std::array<>? You could use just that, ot learn from reading the source

Comment: for pre-C++11, I felt that you could do something by preparing initialization template for each length. init template for length 2 will use init template for length 1 plus one more. mentioned somewhere, maybe in Alexandrescu's Modern C++ Design

Comment: @Nick and ForEveR oh sorry dint read that.

Comment: how can you *safely* do T m_data[N]; ?

Comment: Runtime `b.m_data[]` initialization is OK, or do you want compile-time initialization?

Comment: @Infested Sorry, I did not undestand you.

Comment: @Nick how do you know that N will be positive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I mean what should I to do to get `b.m_data[] = {false, false, false}` after `SafeArray<bool, 3> b;` has been constructed?

I am not sure I understand your question correctly, but if I do, then all you need to do is writing a default constructor that initializes your array:

```
SafeArray() : m_data()
{
}
```

The complete code:

```
template <typename T, int N> class SafeArray
{
public:
    SafeArray() : m_data()
    {
    }
    T &operator[](int index)
    {
        assert(0 <= index && index < N);
        return m_data[index];
    }
private:
    T m_data[N];
};
```

And a [**live example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=c61ad7b024bc57c68e84a25f6830d848-7f4bc2c90970fdf19c48ebf8cc2bae3f).

Comment: Wouldn't `SafeArray() : m_data() {}` so the trick, without the call to `std::fill`?

Comment: @juanchopanza: D'oh! Yes, you're right. Going to edit, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using C++03 (therefore you don't have `std::array`) I would rather recommend you `boost::array` which is, basically, a C++03 implementation of `std::array`. (Actually, `std::array` was inspired by `boost::array`).

Otherwise, make your class an aggregate, that is, (as per C++03 8.5.1/1)

> > An aggregate is an array or class (clause 9) with no user-declared constructor, no private protected non-static data member (clause 11), no base classes (clause 10), and no virtual functions.

Then your class will support aggregate initialization as you want.

**Update:** Reading the OP again (and [Andy Prowl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1932150/andy-prowl)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17233146/1137388)), I'm not sure I understand the question. What I propose here is a way to initialize `SafeArray` at construction time, e.g.,

```
SafeArray<bool, 3> b = { false, false, false };
```

Comment: I thought about this too, but I think the OP wants to guarantee safe access, so they need to keep the array data member private - and that makes the class a non-aggregate

Answer (score 0):

What about...?

```
SafeArray() {
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
        m_data[i] = T();
    }
}
```